# Python file compilation and distinguish, how this happens

Tags: python, compilation

While going through many concepts, this comes to my min (it may be silly). Please advise me how following scenario being achieved

Say in a folder I have "z.pyc" file (no z.py).

Now I created z.py at the same location.

As per my understanding first time execution of z.py will update z.pyc , so from second time trial z.py and z.pyc should give same result.

But it is not happening. z.py and z.pyc are giving distinguish results every time.
Please suggest how this scenario being achieved.

Comment: Please describe the *precise* set of commands you are running, what output you expect to see, and what output you actually see.

Comment: say in a folder I created a file z.py containing "print("first file")". Executed create file z.pyc and deleted z.py. But the z.pyc is there. Later I created z.py in the same location as "print("second file")". and executed. So as per my understanding the old z.pyc should have code of new z.py. But if I am executing z.py it is giving second file and z.pyc giving first file. How python distinguishing the z.pyc not belongs to the z.py present in current location.

Comment: What are the precise commands you use to execute z.py?

Comment: The general python command

python z.py

or 

python z.pyc

any different command I need to execute..

Comment: There's your problem. You ran `python z.pyc`, which is not how one executes python scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*first time execution of z.py will update z.pyc*"

No, "execution of `z.py`" will never create, update, nor reference, `z.py`. Only an `import z` statement will create or make use of `z.pyc`.

1) `.pyc` files are created when one performs an *`import`* of a file, never when run *executes* a file.

2) `import z` will refresh the compiled version, if required.

3) Running `python z.pyc` will always run the compiled version of the file, whereas `python z.py` will never run the compiled version of the file.

So, one sequence of events that might lead to the confusing results above is:

```
$ echo "print 'first file'" > z.py
$ echo "import z" > main.py
$ python main.py
first file
$ echo "print 'second file'" > z.py
$ python z.py
second file
$ python z.pyc
first file
```

The lesson to learn? Never run `python z.pyc`, always run `python z.py`.